# Como mudar a cor da fonte de um JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing

Por toda a internet apenas achei gente querendo saber como estilizar parte do texto e sendo "redirecionado" ao `JTextPane`, então não há respostas para a minha pergunta por aí.

Então lá vai: tenho um `JTextArea` em um `JFrame` como posso trocar a cor da fonte de todo o texto do `JTextArea`?

Código atual:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;    
class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    private JTextArea text;
    public MyFrame(){
        text = new JTextArea();
        text.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        text.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 14));
        //Trocar cor da fonte para branco aqui...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) herda de [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html), que automaticamente ganha [setForeground](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setForeground(java.awt.Color)), portanto, você pode fazer por exemplo:

```
jTextArea.setForeground(Color.RED);
jTextArea.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(r, g, b));
```